# Best Way to share a Android service across all apps

Tags: android, android-service, apk, android-contentprovider

I've following scenario:

A user can download my different apps (say App1, App2, App3 etc) from Google Play. All of them uses a common library/service. Right now, I'm packaging this common service with each and every app. I'm trying to find a better solution for this problem. Is it practical to have this common service published as its own APK (or better solution ?). When user installs App1, App2 etc, it will automatically checks the dependency over the service apk and installs it silently.
I'm not an Android Expert. I need you expert advices on the better architecture to solve this. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: read: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html especially the `Context.startService()` portion.